# I am not able to connect to mysql using laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am able to migrate the migration tables to the database i configured in database.php. But when i am trying to fire following command in routes.php 
$details=DB::query('SELECT * FROM test_user');
 print_r($details);

. I am geeting error on my browser.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please be more specific on what does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a method that you have used as given below:

```
DB::query('SELECT * FROM test_user');
```

Instead you can do it using:

```
// Get all records from "test_user" table
$users = DB::table('test_user')->get();
```

Read the [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/queries) documentation first.